# Jest Mock (for async) documentation seems not to test actual code

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to make a mock for an async test based on [the jest docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#content), but I'm not seeing the value so I must be missing something fundamental. Below is a simplified version of the code I have and my file structure

```
 components
    __mocks__
      services.js
    __tests__
      services.test.js
    services.js
```

`components/services.js`

```
async function getData (req, res) {
  const result = await axios.get(url)
  res.json(result.data)
}
```

`components/__mocks__/services.js`

```
const requestPayloadKey = {
  kindOf: 'complex',
  objectAs: 'key'
}
const rawResponseOne = {
  expected: 'response'
}
const rawResponses = new Map() // should probably be an object. i started with map before remembering the keys must be the same, not just deeply equal but this works for now
rawResponses.set(JSON.stringify(requestPayload), rawResponseOne)

export default function(requestPayload) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.nextTick(
      () =>
      rawResponses.has(JSON.stringify(requestPayloadKey)) ?
      resolve(rawResponses.get(JSON.stringify(requestPayloadKey))) :
      reject({
        error: 'response not found'
      })
    )
  })
}
```

`components/__tests__/services.test.js`

```
jest.mock('../services')
import getData from '../services' // I believe this should now be coming from __mocks__
const requestPayload = {
  kindOf: 'complex',
  objectAs: 'key'
}
const rawResponseOne = {
  expected: 'response'
}
describe('services', () => {
  it('should return raw data from service', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return getData(requestPayload).then(data =>
      expect(data).toEqual(rawResponseOne)
    )
  })
})
```

This seems to be the basic structure that the jest docs are laying out, in which the actual API code isn't run, but rather is *replaced* (not sure if that's the right word) with the code present in the `__mocks__/services.js`. I must be missing something critical and fundamental here because this really isn't testing anything, only that I pass the mock a string and it checks a hardcoded piece of fixture data for it. It doesn't have access to even the error-catching code within *components/services.js*. It seems I could just as easily without the mock do something like

```
expect(rawResponses.get(requestPayloadKey)).toBe(rawResponseOne)
```

#### What am I missing from the documentation that will make this test useful?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. The Jest example from the link explains how to test `getUserName` without hitting the network. In your case you're testing ... what? You'd be testing that `getData` does what's expected with the results of the axios GET.  But I'm not entirely sure what specifically you're trying to test  here.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not analogous to the one in jest docs. What they have is the following:

```
 __mocks__
   request.js
 __tests__
   user-test.js
 user.js
 request.js
```

They are testing the logic in `user.js` by mocking away the network request (in `request.js`). You are mocking the same thing you're trying to test which isn't useful, as you have said yourself.

What would've been an equivalent to their example is something like:

```
 components
    __mocks__
      services.js
    __tests__
      data-processor.test.js
    services.js
    data-processor.js
```

Here you'd mock `services.js` wihin `data-processor.test.js` (with `jest.mock('../services')`), and test data processing logic of `data-processor.js` which relies on `services.js` to get its data.

This means, that you need to keep your logic of working with the data separate from the code that gets the data. The way you get the data is an implementation detail and not important for testing the logic that processes it, hence the mock. This is not specific to jest but applies to structuring your code to be testable in general.